# How to fix "Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds"

Tags: matlab, voronoi

```
 x = gallery('uniformdata',[1,10],0);
 y = gallery('uniformdata',[1,10],1);
 [v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)]); %returns an array V with vertices and a cell array C with a matrix for each cell of the diagram. 
 v = v( ~any( isnan( v ) | isinf( v ), 2 ),: );
 for ii=1:numel(c)
        v(c{ii},:) %contains the vertices to cell number ii, corresponding to centroid x,y(ii,:).     
 end
```

The `v(c{1},:)` seems to execute just fine ,but once it reaches `v(c{2},:)` I get this error

"Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 13)."

NOTE: `numel(v)` returns 13

I tried `for ii=1:numel(c)-1` ,but that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `v = v(...)` changes the array `v`. The indices in `c` no longer match the array `v`.

You should drop that line of code.

Comment: Thanks , I can't believe that was the problem -.-. However, how would I still be able to get rid of those infs and nan values without messing the indices?

Comment: @360codeyoutodeath: you mean you want to remove the cells that have a vertex at infinity? According to the docs, `v(1)` is the vertex at infinity. So you want to find any element of `c` that has a 1 in it and remove that element. I would just iterate over `c` and examine each of the cells.

Comment: The vertex at infinity is part of the Voronoi tessellation. If you want to draw the cells, see [`voronoi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html), which is explicitly 2D, and returns only finite vertices.

Comment: I need the coordinates of all the cells in the voronoi diagram, but I need the inf values deleted from it. Your suggestion on deleting the 1's from the cell array c was a good idea ,but I am having trouble doing so.

Comment: I found this online: ```for ii = 1 : numel(c)
     c{ii} = c{ii}(c{ii} ~= 1);
    end``` and it works!. Thanks for the help